# JSF: How to update the URL without redirect the page?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a JSF page, and I would like to update the content using ajax (re-rendering just some parts), but I also want to update the URL. Is there a way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method, so basically every answer here is possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=history.pushstate